# not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: android, google-analytics

I`m trying to set up Google Analytics and getting this error:

```
The method getInstance(Context) in the type EasyTracker is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
           super.onStart();
           EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
           super.onStop();
           EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method
```

I`m new here so please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what the error is saying is that if you call `getInstance()` you need to provide it a `Context` object. You're doing this within an `Activity`, so `getInstance(this)` should work for you (in this case, `this` will be matching your current `Context`).